# NoClassDefFoundError jdom2 SAXBuilder

Tags: java, xml, tomcat7, jdom-2

I have the following code which compiles fine:

```
        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        org.jdom2.Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml));
        org.jdom2.Element root = doc.getRootElement();
```

However when I deploy it to Tomcat7 and run it, I get this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder

My file structure in Tomcat7:

```
WEB-INF
  |
  +classes
    |
    +-MyClass.java
  |
  +-lib
    |
    + jdom-2.0.6
```

I don't get an error with either org.jdom2.Document or org.jdom2.Element. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at your <TOMCAT_HOME>/logs/catalina.log and see what is happening to the org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder class.

Comment: SAXBuilder is not mentioned anywhere in <TOMCAT_HOME>/logs/catalina.log